# Yeti Launch and Git Repo

Tags: git, permissions, zurb-foundation, zurb-foundation-6, yeti-launch

So I'm new to Foundation and especially using the Yeti Launch application. Why is that if I make New Project with Yeti Launch I cannot make my own repo of it on git.

If I create the project via CLI and use "npm start" than i have permissions on git?

I guess what I'm asking is how/if it's possible to create a new project in Yeti and sync in on my git?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is because Yeti creates a clone of the template you choose from GitHub. Cloning points to the original repo, so you have to do a little extra setup to put the repo on your own GitHub account.

After creating a project from a template in Yeti, do the following:

1. Create a new, empty repo on GitHub
2. In terminal, `cd` to the directory of your project
3. Run `git remote rm origin` to remove the remote you don't have access to
4. Run `git remote add origin https://github.com/your_username/name_of_repo.git` (Replace `your_username` and `name_of_repo` with your info)
5. Run `git push -u origin master` to push the local repo to GitHub

Comment: Thanks Colin. You just deleted my major headache.

Comment: `rm -rf @defawlt/headache`